# Google Sheet Script : How to autoupdate Google Sheet 'in new column'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I imported stock data from *GoogleFinance* to *GoogleSheet*,
and able use Google script for making it auto update on the same cell, 
but do not know how to make it put new data on the next available cell.

This is the one for getting data, which only update the data on Cell A1, I don't know how to make it update the price to B1, C1, D1 for its future update.

```
function GetPrice() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A1').setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price")');
}
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: It will be a good idea to share your code too

Comment: I only have to code for grabbing data function (updated), 
but have not idea about the one to make them input data on new cell. 

Please advise MShoaib91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value to the next column i.e if first value was in A1, now on next function call you want values to be in B1, C1 and continue, you need to update your code to get the last column index and then setting the value to the next column.

```
function GetPrice(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  // increment the column index
  lastCol ++;
  // Setting first parameter i.e row index to 1 for the value to appear in the first row
  sheet.getRange(1, lastCol).setValue('=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price")');
}
```

For understanding of sheet API, you can check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

Comment: Great! You can click the green tick under the most helpful answer to close your question.